# AppCode showing error message [c++]

Tags: c++, ide, appcode

I just start using AppCode 2.5.5 on my MacBook Pro for c++ coding.
The problem is that the IDE keep showing a error warning, but (I think) that there is no error.

That is the Token_stream.h

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

enum class Kind : char {
    name,
    number,
    end,
    plus = '+',
    minus = '-',
    mul = '*',
    div = '/',
    print = ';',
    assign = '=',
    lp = '(',
    rp = ')'
};

struct Token {
    Kind kind;
    string string_value;
    double number_value;
};

class Token_stream {
private:
    void close();
    istream *ip;
    bool owns;
    Token ct {Kind::end};

public:
    Token_stream(istream &s) : ip {&s}, owns {false} {}
    Token_stream(istream *p) : ip {p}, owns {true} {}
    ~Token_stream();
    Token get();
    const Token& current();
    void set_input(istream &s);
    void set_input(istream *p);
};

double error(const string &s);
```

AppCode keep saying that a "***;***" is missing in ***Token ct {Kind::end};***

Can anyone tell me what is going on?

Here is the link to the screenshot: https://app.box.com/s/jgdeufoi2f32aaj00gh9

Thanks.

Comment: Where did you get this code? Why do you think `Token ct {Kind::end};` is valid C++? It doesn't look valid to the parser in my head, either. What did you intend for it to do?

Answer (score 0):

The code is good, that were bugs in AppCode [OC-9218](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/OC-9218), [OC-4724](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/OC-4724).
They would be fixed in the next EAP.